# How to convert data into 2D Array to put into a table

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jtable

I've started a little side project to learn how to extract web data and learn how to use tables with Java. First time working with tables and 2D arrays so I may be going about this the wrong way..
I am trying to extract data from a site and input it into a table and so far I have been able to get the data. I input the data into a single string separated by commas and new lines(csv) called scheduleCsv

```
Sun 02-16-14 09:45 PM,1,REAL TIRED,JUST WACK AT IT,2 - 4,
Sun 02-23-14 08:10 PM,1,BALLERS,REAL TIRED,4 - 11,
Sun 03-02-14 09:00 PM,1,REAL TIRED,EL TRI,1 - 7,
Sun 03-09-14 05:50 PM,1,GO GO POWER RANGERS,REAL TIRED,4 - 9,
Sun 03-16-14 06:40 PM,1,REAL TIRED,GAME OF GROANS,
Sun 03-23-14 09:00 PM,1,HUNGOVER HAT TRICKS,REAL TIRED,
Sun 03-30-14 07:25 PM,1,REAL TIRED,PRESTIGE WORLD WIDE,
Sun 04-06-14 04:20 PM,1,REAL TIRED,BALLERS,
```

Is it possible to input this data into a JTable? I have tried a few different methods from searching around and so far have been unsuccessful. I have another array the specifies column names

```
String[] columnNames = {"Date","Field", "Home Team","Visitor Team", "Score"};
```

and my table is set up as so

```
final JTable scheduleTable = new JTable(data,columnNames);
```

I believe the "data" should be a 2D array..?

Comment: I am a bit confused: how is the data structured? Is it a single String?

Comment: just entering in Google: `JTable` gives the following result: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#JTable(java.lang.Object[][], java.lang.Object[]). So yes, `data` should be a 2D array.

Comment: It may be better to think about entering the data as a List of objects, whose class represents one row of data in that table. So a class that has a date attribute, and whatever other data that csv represents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how the data is obtained, this should not be so difficult:

- If you have one string, then split it by `"\n"` to obtain individual lines
- If you have individual lines, split them by `,` to obtain individual columns

An example:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TableContentsTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        String[] columnNames = {"Date","Field", "Home Team","Visitor Team", "Score"};
        String[][] contents = createTableContents();
        JTable table = new JTable(contents, columnNames);

        f.getContentPane().add(table);
        f.setSize(400,400);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);

    }
    public static String[][] createTableContents()
    {
        String input = 
            "Sun 02-16-14 09:45 PM,1,REAL TIRED,JUST WACK AT IT,2 - 4,"+"\n"+
            "Sun 02-23-14 08:10 PM,1,BALLERS,REAL TIRED,4 - 11,"+"\n"+
            "Sun 03-02-14 09:00 PM,1,REAL TIRED,EL TRI,1 - 7,"+"\n"+
            "Sun 03-09-14 05:50 PM,1,GO GO POWER RANGERS,REAL TIRED,4 - 9,"+"\n"+
            "Sun 03-16-14 06:40 PM,1,REAL TIRED,GAME OF GROANS,"+"\n"+
            "Sun 03-23-14 09:00 PM,1,HUNGOVER HAT TRICKS,REAL TIRED,"+"\n"+
            "Sun 03-30-14 07:25 PM,1,REAL TIRED,PRESTIGE WORLD WIDE,"+"\n"+
            "Sun 04-06-14 04:20 PM,1,REAL TIRED,BALLERS,"+"\n";

        String[] lines = input.split("\n");
        String result[][] = new String[lines.length][];
        for (int i=0; i<lines.length; i++)
        {
            result[i] = Arrays.copyOf(lines[i].split(","), 5);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Perfect solution. Just had to modify it a little to pass in the string as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Max google it, there are many good tutorials. For example: 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html

To read the cvs file I would recommend you to load into List instead of array.

Comment: The data is not in a CSV file it is in a string.